# How to make Sticky Header of table when multiple head

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, meteor

I'm trying to make a table's header sticky. But it doesn't seem to work. This experiment I have been trying with meteor framework.

```
                         <table class="tableclass">
                            <thead class="headclass">
                            <tr class="tr">
                                <th style="color: #ffffff">th content</th>

                                {{#each names}}
                                    <th>{{name}}</th>
                                {{/each}}
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            {{#each peoples}}
                                <thead>
                                <tr class="tr-another">
                                    <th  colspan="100%">
                                   <span id="report"><img id="icons" src="button.svg" width="16px" height="16px">
                                   </span> {{this}}</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class={{this}}>
                                {{>Field}}
                                </tbody>
                            {{/each}}

                        </table>
```

I used following style.

```
tableclass{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:100px;
    }

.outer table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border : 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 1px;
}

.outer table th {
        text-align: left;
        top:0;
        position: sticky;
        background-color: white;  
}
```

can someone please help. I want to make first thead sticky.

Thanks.

Comment: here are a few issues: 1) table may have only one `<thead>`, your example has multiple ones. But `<thead>` may have multiple rows. 2) styles should have `.tableclass`, but your styles without a dot. Fix it at first. Check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xlycdf. It has working example based on your code

Answer (score 1):

According to [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/) you can't set `position: sticky;` on `<thead>` nor a `<tr>`. but you can sticky a `<th>`. it's weird but it works.

You set this property on the class `.outer table th`. but I didn't see this class in your HTML!

Actually based on your HTML code, you can write this:

```css
.headclass th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you css should be:

```
.headclass {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```