# I have multiple tables on a page of which I want the headers to be sticky

Tags: html, css

I have multiple tables on a page of which I want the headers to be sticky.

Here is my fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deeprony7/sejt1ngw/70/)

Here is the CSS involving the div wrapper and the table header:

```
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.headclass th{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

[I tried to follow this answer, but can't get it working on my fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570206/how-to-make-sticky-header-of-table-when-multiple-head)

Comment: On the second table you didn't add class="headclass" to your thead

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `position: sticky;` on `<thead>` and/or `<tr>` element but on `<th>`

Remove that class that you already created:

```
.headclass th{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Instead, use this:

```
.headclass tr.bg-info th {
  background: #17a2b8;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```